# Render or update a page while still running inside a method

Tags: jsf-2, rendering

I was wondering if you could render or update a page while you still inside a method;
here is an example: 
the .xhtml file:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton value="change" actionListener="#{bean.changeText}">
        <f:ajax render="out" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:outputLabel id="out" value="#{bean.text}" />
</h:form>
```

and here is the changeText Method:

```
public void changeText() throws InterruptedException{
    text = "test1"; 
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    text = "test2";
}
```

Now is it possible to set the output label (id = out) to be rendered (or changed) to "test1", then after the 2 second have elapsed it changes to "test2"?
Well looking at the JSF life cycle i thought it isnt possible, but maybe i got the life cycle wrong, or one of you guys know a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The render response only starts once the action method returns.

There are basically 2 ways to achieve the desired behavior: polling or pushing. Based on your question history, you're using Java EE 7 + JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces. You could for pushing use [PrimeFaces `<p:socket>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml) or homegrow one using Java EE 7's new WebSocket API (JSR-356).

Comment: I never heard of polling or pushing, but yea i guess it does the deal ... thank you ...

Comment: This example is perfect for what i'm asking http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/pollStartStop.jsf